# How to reconnect anonymous user in XMPP/Jabber

Tags: javascript, xmpp

I'm working on browser javascript xmpp client that connects anonymously to my server.

But when a user reloads the page or leaves it and subsequently returns to it I need
to reconnect to the server with the same anonymous account. How can I do this?

I'm using Strophe library (xmpp over bosh). So I already tried to do the following:

```
connection.connect(jid, "", onConnect);
```

this results in failure response from server:

```
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'>
<failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">
<not-authorized/></failure>
</body>
```

and also:

```
connection.attach(jid, sid, rid, onConnect);
```

where jid, rid and sid are from cookies in both cases.
The second method is ok, but I can't manage with rid parameter correctly in all popular browsers.

Comment: Please provide much more information. What jabber client are you using? What have you tried? What errors or log messages do you get, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach is to use [XEP-0077](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0077.html): "In-Band Registration" to create a brand new JID of the form [UUID]@yourhost on first login, with random password, then log back in to that account when you need to reconnect.  Sweep through and delete the unused accounts periodically.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using jQuery (see $(document).ready). The example bellow uses Strophe for establishing BOSH communication to the XMPP server. The user joins the MUC room.

```
function onConnect(status) {
  if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
    var joined = false;
    var participants = {};
    $('#events').html('<text class="textmainleft">XMPP connection established. Ready to rock n roll!</text>');
    connection.send($pres().c('priority').t('-1'));
    connection.addHandler(notifyUser, null, 'message', 'groupchat', null, null);
    connection.send(
      $pres({
        to: '[% groupchatroom %]@xmppserver.dom/' + "[% nickname %]"
      }).c('x', {xmlns: 'http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'}));
  } else if (status == Strophe.Status.AUTHFAIL) {
      $(location).attr('href', AUTHFAIL_URL);
  } else if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNFAIL) {
    $(location).attr('href', AUTHFAIL_URL);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  var user_id = [% user_id %];
  connection = new Strophe.Connection(BOSH_SERVICE);
  connection.connect( "[% jid %]", "[% password %]", onConnect);
  // Additional custom code goes here                                      
});
```

Comment: what jid and password I should use here for anonymous method?

Comment: To be honest I don't know. I guess it depends on your XMPP server configuration. I always use valid registered jid/pas. Which XMPP server do you use? I'm sure some search will yield a result.

Comment: In your question, you say that you can connect anonymously the first time you load the page, right?

Comment: yes, i do it with jid = "mydomain.org" and server gives me new anonymous jid like this jid="a4714f0@mydomain.org", I want to proceed using the same anonymous user after visitor reloads the page, but I haven't succeded to do so.